# Django allauth page redirections

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have used diango allauth for login signup. After signing up or logging in a form appears where I need to enter a few details and submit it. After submitting the form it cannot be resubmitted again and another page appears where i can print my submitted data. So whenever I login after successful submission of the form the preview page should appear. The form page should not and cannot be appeared again. How will I attain this?

Comment: did you try adding login_ redirect url?
Can u show settings page of your app

Comment: Yes, login redirect url is working but I want to change the login redirect url dynamically after submitting a particular form

Comment: What do you mean by "change the login redirect dynamically"??

Comment: When a user logs in, a form appears and after submitting the form the user is redirected to another page say xyz.html. If the same user logs in again, the xyz.html page should appear and not the form

Comment: It is better to check using a flag and redirect to separate views

Comment: How will attain that? Can you give a short example?